# Elasticsearch java client api to call the cat rest endpoints

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have seen Elasticsearch has so many action classes implemented to get the cat functionality like RestIndicesAction etc,.

Is there any elastic search client api to call those endpoints.

For an example, how can i implement elasticsearch api to get "_cat/indices"

Comment: The JavaScript client API provides a [`cat.indices` call](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#api-cat-indices) that you can use.

Answer (score 3):

In Java, given an instance of the `Client` class:

```
client.admin().indices()
      .getIndex(new GetIndexRequest())
      .actionGet().getIndices();
```

If you want to get only the indices whose name follows a given expression:

```
client.admin().indices()
      .getIndex(new GetIndexRequest().indices("regex-*"))
      .actionGet().getIndices();
```